# Space Warps & Frame Invariance

Tags: general-relativity, warp-drives

[The Alcubierre Warp Drive in Higher Dimensional 
Spacetime](http://earthtech.org/publications/davis_STAIF_conference_2.pdf) (H. G. White & E. W. Davis), among other sources, proposes that the x-axis symmetry paradox for Alcubierre-style warp drives can be resolved by interpreting the warp field as producing a scalar boost on a pre-existing velocity. If that is the case, how can it obey frame invariance?
In other words, how does the boost "know" which velocity, in which inertial frame, it's supposed to be multiplying?

Comment: FYI that's a crackpot paper written by known charlatans. Life is too short to waste reading anything they write.

Comment: Title & Author info added.
@ChrisWhite - they are not known 'charlatans' to me. Harold White is employed by NASA and both authors have PhDs physics. If you have references that indicate that they are in fact guilty of fraud or incompetence, I'm happy to be enlightened, but while warp drives may be "far out" I've seen no indication that research into Alcubierre warp drives deserves to be called "crackpot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an uncommon interpretation that the Alcubierre drive acts as a multiplier of an existing subluminal velocity. The trouble is that the Alcubierre metric describes the drive in constant motion that doesn't change with time. It tells us nothing about how the drive accelerated to that speed or decelerated from it. The drive is moving in whatever direction the metric says because that's how the metric was constructed.

I've seen very few papers on the Alcubierre metric that even mention the question of acceleration, and none that treat it in detail. I'd guess the ratio of hardness of the problem to interest in the outcome is too high for most researchers. The paper [The Alcubierre Warp Drive: On the Matter of Matter](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5708) examines it briefly although the authors' interest is really on the effect of matter caught up in the drive.

So I'm afraid there is no answer to your question.

Comment: I suppose it is not terribly surprising that an answer does not yet exist. But what I find really baffling is that, as far as I can tell from my own searching, no one even acknowledges the existence of the question. It seems to me that proving that your warp bubble theory doesn't violate frame invariance should be a pretty high priority before trying to design interferometer experiments around it.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: No-one is going to win a Nobel prize for theoretical calculations of FTL drives (unless of course you actually create one :-) so for physicists it's the sort of thing you do on a Friday afternoon. The interferometer experiment isn't designed to build an FTL drive, it's designed to see if that type of curvature can be created by a non-exotic stress-energy tensor. This seems to me to be an interesting experiment and the relationship to the Alcubierre metric is incidental.